# Join images with data frames in r

Tags: r, image, dataframe, jpeg, r-grid

This is probably a very basic question, but I am not familiar with images in R.

I want a **PDF file** with two joined imported images and a data frame as the image exemplifies:

[image: Final output]

This is the code that I am using but is not working.

```
library(grid)
library(useful)
library(magick)

# Read external images
imageA <- image_read("imageA.jpg") 
imageB <- image_read("imageB.jpg") 

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(1:3)

# Create PDF
pdf("/Mydocument.pdf", width = 10, height = 20)
grid.newpage() 

# Create matrix layout
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 3)))

# Place elements inside grid
print(imageA, vp = vplayout(1, 1)) 
print(imageB, vp = vplayout(1, 2))
print(df, vp = vplayout(1, 3)) 

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code achieves what you want:

```
require('magick')

# Read external images
frink = image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")
logo = image_read("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png")
imgs = c(frink, logo)

# concatenate them left-to-right (use 'stack=T' to do it top-to-bottom)
side_by_side = image_append(imgs, stack=F)

# save the pdf
image_write(side_by_side, path = "just_a_test.pdf", format = "pdf")
```

which gives this image:

[image]

You may want to scale the images vertically with `image_scale(imgs, "x960")` - changing `960` with whatever height you want, in pixels.

The [vignette of `magick`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) explains this and much more: it is an incredibly valuable resource to work on images with R.

---

A note: if you are using R for the sole purpose of concatenating images, you are doing it wrong: use directly the [`convert img1.png img2.gif +append new_combined.pdf`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append) syntax of the `convert` commandline tool. It ships with the Image Magick library, the R `magick` package is a wrapper to it.

But if you have further treatments to do with R, then you can simply convert the image as a `raster` and continue working with it: `as.raster(side_by_side)`

Comment: I aprreciate a lot your help. I am doing treatments with R. I want to place a data frame aside the images. How do you suggest I have to proceed?

Comment: @Alfredo_MF `require('raster'); your_raster = as.raster(side_by_side);` would be the way to go. Images are commonly stored as raster in R, this is a very convenient way to manipulate them (for example, `plot(your_raster)` just works). I don't see why you would need a data.frame storing RGB codes for each pixels, but you can always get it like so: `as.data.frame(as.matrix(your_raster))` :)